# What files should be audited on Turnkey Linux Core 14 (Debian Linux Variant)?

Tags: linux, audit

If I'm looking to audit [file / permission changes](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) on Turnkey Linux Core 14; what directories / files / permissions should I audit to make sure nobody has broken into the thing?

If you are unfamiliar with TurnKey, assume that I am asking about a minimal headless Debian server with OpenSSH-server installed

Comment: Because this is about specific changes on a specific distribution, this should probably go to the Linux site.

Comment: @schroeder okay go ahead and move it there...

Comment: at this point it's too old - you might have to delete this one and create new on unix.stackexchange.com